# На мобильных не отображается прозрачный фон

Tags: html, css

Есть div со свойством `background: rgb(28, 15, 33, 0.5);`
На мобильном телефоне в браузере Chrome этот полупрозрачный фон вообще не отображается. Просто как будто фон не задан. Как это реализуется, чтобы всё работало на мобильных?

Comment: `background: rgba(28, 15, 33, 0.5);`

Comment: @UModeL. Так просто, но сработало. Благодарю:)